# ASP.NET core model validation doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, model-validation

According to Microsoft documentation, if a model property is not-nullable, it is considered required by default, so there's no need to explicitly add the `[Required]` attribute.

> By default, the validation system treats non-nullable parameters or properties as if they had a [Required] attribute. Value types such as decimal and int are non-nullable.
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2#required-attribute

But that's not practically true. Let's say I have the following model:

```
public class Model
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

If the request doesn't contain `Age` in its body, a 0 is bound to the Age property and model validation doesn't fail. Even with `[Required]`, model validation still doesn't fail and 0 is assigned to `Age`. So how do I make properties with not-nullable types really "required"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three options imho:

- Validate yourself that `Age` is not the `default` value
- Use a `Range` attribute
- Make it required and `nullable`

```cs
[Required]
public int? Age { get; set; }
```

It depends very much on your circumstances if nullable-required is a nice solution or just a dirty workaround.

Comment: [`[BindRequired]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2#customize-model-binding-behavior-with-attributes) might be a better option for this.

Comment: @KirkLarkin still ModelState.IsValid is true, maybe it just work before entring action with ```opt.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = value;``` set to `default`, or `false`, but not `true`.